# Hash function collisions analysis

Tags: hash

How do I ensure that a hash function has low collisions ? Or another way to ask this questions would be, how do I analyze how good a hash generator function is ?

Comment: You ensure that a hash function has low collision probability by using an existing, cryptographically secure one (such as SHA-1).

Comment: @MattBall: What if my hashtable is backed by an array with fewer than 2-to-the-power-of-160 entries? (My universe has a crippling atom shortage, y'know.)